# Decompress Compress Rich Text field

Tags: c#, html, outlook, mapi, richtext

I have an image column in a datatable containing compressed RichText data. I suppose this was obtained from Outlook (PR_RTF_COMPRESSED property or something). I need to decompress it. Using C#, I'm trying the following, but I'm getting a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExceptions and can't figure it out.

I found a couple of old links asking this question, with no resolved answers. Here's a snippet of my code using c#.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IStream streamOut;

        string con = "connection string";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select top 10 columnInCompressedRichTextFormat FROM tableWithCompressedRichTextData", new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString));
        DataTable x = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        a.Fill(x);
        a.Dispose();

        foreach (DataRow r in dtResults.Rows)
        {
            byte[] arrayOfBytes = (byte[]) r["columnInCompressedRichTextFormat"];
            IStream i = CreateIStreamFromBytes(arrayOfBytes);
            WrapCompressedRTFStream(input, 0, out streamOut);
        }
    }

    public IStream CreateIStreamFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        IntPtr hglobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, hglobal, bytes.Length);

        IStream stream = null;

        CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hglobal, true, out stream);

        return stream;
    }

    [DllImport("Mapi32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    private static extern void
        WrapCompressedRTFStream(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IStream lpCompressedRTFStream,
        uint ulflags,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IStream lpUncompressedRTFStream
        );

    [DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    static extern int CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr hGlobal,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fDeleteOnRelease,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IStream ppstm
        );

    public const uint MAPI_MODIFY = 0x00000001;
    public const uint STORE_UNCOMPRESSED_RTF = 0x00008000;
}
```

WrapCompressedRTFStream is throwing the error. Any ideas?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help you without the error.  Follow the guidance here http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/ImageOfAnException (scan down to the section about getting exception details)

Comment: You also need to make sure you are loading the right instance of msmapii32.dll instead of statically linking to mapi32.dll. Look at the MFCMAPI source code to see how it is done.

Comment: Does anybody know the difference bet WrapCompressedRTFStream and WrapCompressedRTFStreamEx?

Comment: @Will - the exception details don't help too much -System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040605): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040605
   at proj.Form1.WrapCompressedRTFStream(IStream lpCompressedRTFStream, UInt32 ulflags, IStream& lpUncompressedRTFStream)
   at ...

Comment: @MikeTurner please, follow the guidance at the link (you skipped the part about pasting it into a comment).  Don't assume it won't help.

Comment: @Will -  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147219963
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040605
  Source=proj
  StackTrace:
       at proj.Form1.WrapCompressedRTFStream(IStream lpCompressedRTFStream, UInt32 ulflags, IStream& lpUncompressedRTFStream)
       at proj.Form1..ctor() in ...
       at proj.Program.Main() in ...
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,

Comment: Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

Comment: @Dmitry - specifying exactly which dll to load with full path didn't help :(

Comment: The error code is MAPI_E_NOT_INITIALIZED, which means you did nto call MAPIInitialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completely different approach that seems to work - 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?669883-NET-3-5-RtfDecompressor-Decompress-RTF-From-Outlook-And-Exchange-Server

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.  I was able to make a VB.NET class library and then referenced it from my C# project.  (Note: for the less lazy folks/C# purists -- once you've compiled the VB.NET class library, it's possible to decompile it into C# if you're so inclined; using a tool like ILSPY, etc.)